# FourSquare explore API doesn't work with offest

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to hit the ends point 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore' with the initial parameters

```
{v='20180323',
near='SFO',
radius = 100000,
section='topPicks',
limit=20 }
```

and later on by adding offset = 20 to the above dictionary. I am expecting results from 21-40 in the second response, but I am getting the same response as my first query.

Comment: For me work just fine. Can you please show your URL?

Comment: Works fine for me. Your radius is huge, maybe its overloading things.